# Full class template specialization with forward declarations

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

It appears a forward declaration is causing an issue when specializing some template functions within a template class.  I am specializing the class also as it's necessary in order to specialize the function, and this seems to be causing the issue.

Edit: Second question about pre-creating functions for process function:

processor.H

```
namespace OM{

template<typename MatchT>  //fwd decl.  ERROR 2. see below.
class Manager;

template<typename MatchT>
class Processor
{
   public:
            Processor(Manager<MatchT>& mgr_):_manager(mgr_) {}
            template<int P>
            void process();

            void doProcess();

   private:
            Manager<MatchT>&   _manager;
            template<int P, int... Ps>
            struct table : table<P-1,P-1, Ps... > {};

            template<int... Ps>
            struct table<0, Ps...>
            {
                static constexpr void(*tns[])() = {process<Ps>...};
            };

            static table<5> _table;
};

}

#include "processor.C"
```

processor.C

```
namespace OM{

#include "MyManager.H" (includes MyManager/MyConfig)
template<typename MatchT>
template<int P>
inline void Processor<MatchT>::process()
{
    ...
    _manager.send();    //this works..
}

template <> template <>
inline void Processor<MyManager<MyConfig> >::process<1>()
{
   _manager.send(); //ERROR 1 - see below.
}

//ERROR here:
template<typename MatchT>
void doProcess()
{
  Processor<MatchT>::_table::tns[2]();  ERROR 3 below.
}

}
```

compile errors:

```
1. error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Manager <MyManager<MyConfig> >'

2. error: declaration of 'class Manager<MyManager<MyConfig> >'
   class Manager;

3. error: no type name '_table' in "class Processor<MyManager<MyConfig> >'
    I'm not calling this from a specialized function, so I'm not sure
    why I'm getting this.
```

I can move things around a bit to ensure the _manager calls are not within the specialized functions, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: `namespace OM{ .. #include "MyManager.H"` So when this header is included, you will end up with `namespace OM{ namespace OM{` in your final code.

Comment: `//this works..` it probably doesn't actually, it just isn't being instantiated yet.

Comment: Maanger is defined in another file in the same translation unit.

Comment: If I remove the specialization it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this, I think now I get a similar result.

The problem is the template specialisation and forward declaration together. This should be eqvivalent:

```
template<typename T> struct A;

template<typename T> class B
{
    template<int N>
    T f();
};

template<typename T> class B<A<T>>
{
    A<T> *a;
    template<int N>
    T f();
};

template<typename T> struct A{ T i=1; };//works

template<>
template<>
int B<A<int>>::f<1>()
{
    return a->i + 1;
}

//template<typename T> struct A { T i = 1; };//error

int main()
{
    B<A<int>> b;
}
```

The compilation for templates comes in two stages:

First, it checks syntax and (some) dependence. So, for example if `a` in `B<A<T>>` was not a pointer/reference, but the object itself, it could compile, if that `B<A<T>>` is constructed after `A` is defined. (worked for me)

So the second is when the compiler inserts the arguments, here, the compiler must know all objects to generate code.

When fully specialising, as above, the compiler is forced to know all types. It already knows, that `f` function depends on the implementation of `A`, so it cannot generate the code.

Therefore you have to define `A` or `Manager` before the function specialisation.

Comment: I see..  It's a bit of work for me to change files so that A is defined first.. I may do that, but for now I've moved calls to manager out of the specialized functions.    Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @ggs I rewrote the example, now this should work for you. You are welcome :)

Comment: thanks I see it..    I have 1 more question about this, but it might be better to ask a separate question for it..  Thank you.

Comment: edited the code with last question.. I'm trying to pre-create "process" functions and then call them by indexing into an array.  Since I'm declaring "_table" as static in a template class there is no need to define outside correct?   Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: I'm sure there is a simpler way of doing this, even with template metaprograming. Anyway, I don't understand what "tns" is, neither does my compiler.

Capy paste errors:
 template<int P, int.. Ps>
(you probaly had 3 dots);

Processor(Manager<MatchT>& mgr_) :_manager(mgr_)
(missing {} from the end)

Comment: tns is just an array of pointers.. I've edited to add the 3rd dot.  This works if I make the class non template with no specializations.   I'm doing it this way because the index to the array is not known until run time and it will have a large range.  I'd rather avoid switch or if statements.